# PHP: How to get the key of value passed by value / reference?

Tags: php, arrays, associative-array

How can I get the key of value passed as a value / reference in PHP?

For example:

```
$city = array('city_1'=>'Delhi', 'city_2'=>'Delhi');

function caller(){
    callee($city['city_2']);
}

function callee($city_val){ //pass by reference can also be used
    //how do I get 'city_2' from $city_val?
}
```

I require this functionality since the `callee()` might be called by more than one `caller()`. I need the key values so that I can insert a new item in a global array inside the `callee()`.

I have thought of passing the key as one of the parameters, but was wondering if there are other alternatives.

**Note:** The values in `$city` array might be repeated, so I can't use any search / loop mechanism.

Comment: maybe, better to set array as global and send the key than find it in array?

Comment: Yes, the array can be global (I've edited my question), but the values might be repeated. A particular value may correspond to more than one key.

Comment: @theScorpion You can't do that, since there is now way to get that information, if you don't pass it

Comment: @Rizier123 so passing the key as a parameter is the only solution?

Comment: @theScorpion yes + the simplest